# I want to remove index.php in the link

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, web, mariadb

I created my website using WordPress with Apache, PHP and MariaDB. Everything is working just fine. I created a page in the WordPress but when I open the page, the link included `index.php` `http://localhost:8081/gis/index.php/wfs-map/` but my WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) is using this link `http://localhost:8081/gis`.

I tried to change the permalink where it automatically chose Custom Structure and the link is this `http://localhost:8081/gis` and in the box stated
`/index.php/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/`. But when I remove the `index.php`, my page display an error

> ##### Not Found
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server.

How can I remove the `index.php`?

Comment: i found the answer by the help of AI finally after so long... i allow All for AllowOverride and i remove index.php at my DirectoryIndex. Both in httpd.conf.

Comment: Stack Overflow questions must not be resolved via comment.  This page should be either self-deleted, closed as a duplicate of some earlier Stack Overflow page that supplies the correct advice, or marked as resolved by posting an educational answer and awarding it the green tick.

Comment: ...as above. See the [tour], [ask] and [answer] for more guidance on how to use the site correctly and effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can Simply Change The WordPress URL Structure From `Settings < Permalinks`

And, Change The URL Pattern From Custom To postname:

[image]

If You Still See The Error On Page, Then Maybe You add The Link With `index.php` in your page content.

Comment: I once tried this but it display error but i already found another solution. Thank you for answering my question! 